# $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e^{ax}+e^{bx}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Could you please give me some hints about evaluating this integration?

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e^{ax}+e^{bx}}dx$$

where $a>0$, $b>0$ and $a\neq b$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assume $b> a,$ and let $u= e^{(a-b)x}.$  This should reduce it to a well-known integral.

Answer (score 5):

If $a<b$,$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty\tfrac{e^{-bx}dx}{1+e^{-(b-a)x}}&=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n\int_0^\infty e^{-b-n(b-a)x}dx\\&=\tfrac{1}{b-a}\sum_{n\ge0}\tfrac{(-1)^n}{n+\tfrac{b}{b-a}}\\&=\tfrac{1}{b-a}\Phi(-1,\,1,\,\tfrac{b}{b-a})\end{align}$$in terms of the [Lerch transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Definition). If $a\ne b$, the result is $\tfrac{1}{|a-b|}\Phi\left(-1,\,1,\,\tfrac{\max\{a,\,b\}}{|a-b|}\right)$.